# List of files changed in top commit in shallow clone

Tags: git, continuous-integration, shallow-clone

Is it possible to get a list of files changed in the latest commit in a shallow-clone repository (clone depth = 1)?

In my CI server I would like to fetch only the latest commit, due to performance reasons, and take further actions based on locations of files changed in the latest commit. This is to improve CI's responsiveness by avoiding unnecessary steps.

Currently I am doing fetch with depth of 2, and using the following to detect changes in `dir_a`:

```bash
diff_dir_a=$( git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD -- dir_a )
if [ ${#diff_dir_a} -gt 1 ]; then changes_dir_a=true; else changes_dir_a=false; fi
```

Depth of 2 is needed to have an ancestor to diff against.

After reading some docs I have found out that I can change the first line to:

```bash
diff_dir_a=$( git show --diff-merges=1 --pretty='' --name-only -- dir_a )
```

I'm using `--pretty=''` to suppress the commit information and `--diff-merges=1` to show changes agains first parent in case of merge commits.

The second version produces the same output for normal clones, but to my surprise for shallow clone with depth of 1, it lists all files contained in the directory, regardless of whether they were changed in the latest commit.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Is this just a quirk in git's way of handling shallow clones, or is it a bug? I find this misleading that `git show` command gives different output for the same commit SHA for repositories cloned with different options.

Comment: The depth should be at least 2. Otherwise, it compares with the empty tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git` doesn't store *diffs*, it stores *the complete content of each commit*.

When `git` displays a diff (or a list of changed files, or ...) between two commits, it doesn't output something it has kept in its storage, it *computes it* by comparing the 2 contents.
Commands that apparently look at 1 commit, like `git show` or `git log -1`, actually need to also have access to the commit's parent(s) if you want to display "the commit's diff" correctly.

This is the reason why you need at least `--depth=2`, and why `--depth=1` won't work in your situation.

Comment: one extra point: this may seem like a limitation, but the reason why shallow clones can easily be obtained at all is precisely because, when you ask "give me only that specific commit", git can easily give you its complete content

Comment: The first line is crucial, thanks for reminder on git's data model :-)

Comment: Could it be called a deficiency in git's manual that it does not mention this problem? Or in git's implementation that does not warn that those ostensibly "1 commit" commands do not have access to a proper ancestor to compute output agains?